# What is the recommended way to separate environments within AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

What approaches can be taken in order to separate environments when using AWS API gateway?
For example, I realize I could simply create a unique account per environment. However, I also would like to leverage the developer portal and dont want to duplicate my efforts any more than I have to.

Based on my little experience with AWS, I'd imagine there are two approaches:

1. Create unique instance within a unique account
2. Create a single account and use stage variables

Lets assume for example that I have 3 environments

- DEV
- STAGE
- PROD

(with the option of having a PREPROD environment perhaps)

Perhaps creating unique account per env?
I want to know the recommended best practice for separating environments for ENTERPRISE applications. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Within a single API Gateway API, you can create different versions of your API configuration using [Stages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-stages.html). Stages can be dev, beta, prod etc. which will have snapshots of different configurations of your API during development.

You may also want to look at [Canary Deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/canary-release.html)s.

Comment: This may not work necessarily if I am using different accounts per environment. Its almost like the assumption here is that there is always more than 1 environment per account.